# Found error while going to fetch using ripple lib function getTransactions(address,Options)

Tags: ripple

[MissingLedgerHistoryError(Server is missing ledger history in the 
 specified range)] error found

options.minLedgerVersion = +req.query.minLedgerVersion;
          
options.maxLedgerVersion = +req.query.maxLedgerVersion;
          
options.types = ['payment'];
        
        
  api.connect().then(() => {
         
   /* begin custom code ------------------------------------ */
         
   return api.getTransactions(req.query.address,options)
        
    }).then(transaction => {
         
       console.log("Transactions info ::: ",transaction);
              
res.status(200).json(formatter.simpleFormat(transaction,true,"success"
));
           
    }).catch(err => {
          
       console.log(err);
           
      res.status(500).json(formatter.simpleFormat(null,false,"error"));
               });

Answer (score 0):

You'd find your answer in the response returned by the [server_info](https://developers.ripple.com/server_info.html) method.
Look for: `result/info/complete_ledgers` and see if your requesting ledgers are included